# how restrict view in MS word 2010?

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I have a word file containing many paragraph. I have a heading for each paragraph.Also listed all heading in a single page. What i want is, When user click on heading it can view only that paragraph only. he will not able to view other paragraph. To view other paragraph user need to comeback to the page where all headings are listed.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would try to handle it is to put each paragraph into its own Continuous section and set all of the text as hidden.  On the page where you have your headings, put a checkbox next to each one and in the checkbox properties, you can assign it to run a macro (remember to do this after you write your macros).

Now you just write a number of simple macros (one for each paragraph you have) that will change the font property of that paragraph by turning the **hidden** setting **off**, while changing the font properties of every other paragraph by turning the **hidden** settings **on**.

Now for your checkboxes, you'll need to set them up so that if one is selected, the rest of them are unselected.  (You may be able to simply use a radio button instead of a checkbox, but I can't remember off the top of my head if radio buttons allow you to run a macro when selected.)

The thing you need to keep in mind is that some people may have their Word settings set up to always show hidden text, which would ruin the point of keeping stuff hidden.  However, I believe you may get around that by adding another macro that turns that setting off as soon as the document is opened.